# Configuring VMWare DHCP Server to provide static IP

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am on Windows 8.1, VMware Workstation. I read many articles about assigning  static IPs to guest OSs, which ask to modify the `vmnetdhcp.conf` file. However I have some doubts. (I have guest OSs connected to VMnet0 Auto-bridging network)

**1.** When I open up `vmnetdhcp.conf` file on my machine, it contained virtual ethernet segement settings, but none of my guest OSs:

```
# Virtual ethernet segment 3
# Added at 07/05/15 13:50:52
subnet 192.168.73.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.73.128 192.168.73.254;            # default allows up to 125 VM's
option broadcast-address 192.168.73.255;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.73.1;
option domain-name "localdomain";
default-lease-time 1800;
max-lease-time 7200;
}
host VMnet3 {
    hardware ethernet 00:50:56:C0:00:03;
    fixed-address 192.168.73.1;
    option domain-name-servers 0.0.0.0;
    option domain-name "";
}
# End
```

So was confused should I put my guest OS settings here.

**2.**  Also articles asks something put like this:

```
host ubuntu {
   hardware ethernet 00:0C:29:16:2A:D6;
   fixed-address 192.168.84.132;
}
```

I can find `hardware ethernet` in my `.vmx` file. However what about `ubuntu`. I have several VMs which are created from copy pasting same original Fedora VM. Thus all these VMs have same name (Fedora 20 new 64-bit.vmx) for their `.vmx` file. Should I put same name if I have to configure static IPs for all those VMs?

**3.** Also notice this name have spaces in it. Will this work?

Comment: How could be your guest in virtual network if is bridged with your physical network adapter?

Comment: ohh I think I am missing some understanding of the virtual networks. So I have to create new private virtual network and then assign IPs?

Comment: In your guest machine details the network adapter should be in your favourite virtual network and then dhcp from that network will provide ip address